# ODE help. $u''(x) +(-2 -x^2 )u = 0 ,\quad 0<x<1,\quad u'(0)=u'(1) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$u''(x) +(-2 -x^2 )u = 0 ,\quad 0<x<1,\quad u'(0)=u'(1) = 0.$

I'm not sure where to even start. What method?

Answer (score 3):

$u\equiv0$ is a solution. Are there any others? The answer is no. To see this, multiply the equation by $u$ and integrate between $0$ and $1$, to get
$$
\int_0^1u''(x)\,u(x)\,dx=\int_0^1(2+x)^2\,(u(x))^2\,dx.
$$
The right hand side is non-negative. Integrating by parts and using the boundary conditions, we see that the left hand side is non-positive. It follows that
$$
\int_0^1(2+x)^2\,(u(x))^2\,dx=0
$$
and $u\equiv0$.

This argument works for any equation $u''(x)=V(x)\,u(x)$ with $V(x)\ge0$ and boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$, $u(0)=u'(1)=0$, $u'(0)=u(1)=0$, or $u'(0)=u'(1)=0$.